# Designning for different screen resolutions

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I'm working on a J2ME applicatoin using LWUIT and would like to support most of the major resolutions available on the market. Back in Android development, I had four sets of resolutions, Ldpi, Mdpi, Hdpi and XHigh, and behind the scenes Android maps the device resolution to any of these four sets, is there something similar in LWUIT for raster graphics, some way to map the dimensions to a grouped set of resolutions.

Regards.

Yehia A.Salam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at multi-images in the Resource Editor, they allow defining separate resources for separate devices and the border wizard can implicitly cut an image to a multi-image border.

Comment: but how can i group resolutions together, for example devices with resolutions like 840x600, 800x600 and 800x550 would take the same resource, and devices with 320x240, 320x260 would take the same resource, would i implement this from the code or the resource editor?

Comment: You need to read about layout management and styling. LWUIT is not like polish. You need to create UI's that will seamlessly adapt to different sizes by using proper layouts and style definitions. Look at the code for LWUITDemo, tzone demo etc. and try them on devices to see how well they adapt to resolutions. They do this using a combination of layouts, theme settings and multi-images.